# Removing self-loops from undirected networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have created a graph from list of nodes using `networkx`. It has self loops. How to remove them? Following is sample:

```py
import networkx as NX
G = NX.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,1)
print(G.edges())
```

Prints: `[(1, 2), (1, 1)]`

I don't want `(1, 1)` edge.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

(instructions for networkx 1.x below)

If you're using networkx 2.x try

```
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))
```

If you have a `MultiGraph` (which for example `configuration_model` produces), this may not work if you have an older release of 2.x with a minor bug.  If so and you don't want to upgrade, then you need to convert this into a list before removing edges.

```
G.remove_edges_from(list(nx.selfloop_edges(G)))
```

This bug has been corrected https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/4068.

---

In **version 1.x** (when I originally answered this question), it was:

```
G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges())
```

Comment: This is cleaner than what I suggested. If you don't have a way to remove on generation (e.g. if graph is in an awkward file format) then do it this way!

Answer (score 14):

The selfloop methods were deprecated as graph methods in favor of networkx functions in version 2.0.

version 1.x:

```
G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges())
```

version 2.x:

```
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous method will be deprecated: use nx.selfloop_edges() instead

Answer (score 1):

The method [`remove_edge`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edge.html?highlight=remove_edge#networkx.Graph.remove_edge) does what you need. Simply filter for when the edge source and destination are the same:

```
for u, v in G.edges_iter():
    if u == v: 
        G.remove_edge(u,v)
```

Comment: Another thing you could do is filter the input list before creating the graph.  But you'd need to show how you make your graphs to show how to filter that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This one works at the time of creating graph.