# Remove selfloops from NetworkX MultiDiGraph causes runtime error

Tags: python, networkx

I have a NetworkX MultiDiGraph that contains selfloops.  According to the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html), this is a valid property of a MultiDiGraph.

> A MultiDiGraph holds directed edges. Self loops are allowed.

But when I try to remove the selfloops from the MultiDiGraph using `MG.remove_edges_from(MG.selfloop_edges())`, the following warning in generated:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ff3391f2296f> in <module>()
      1 # remove selfloop edges from the graph
----> 2 MG.remove_edges_from(MG.selfloop_edges())

~/Program_Files/miniconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/classes/multigraph.py in remove_edges_from(self, ebunch)
    603         []
    604         """
--> 605         for e in ebunch:
    606             try:
    607                 self.remove_edge(*e[:3])

~/Program_Files/miniconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/classes/function.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   1154                 return ((n, n)
   1155                         for n, nbrs in G.adj.items()
-> 1156                         if n in nbrs for d in nbrs[n].values())
   1157         else:
   1158             return ((n, n) for n, nbrs in G.adj.items() if n in nbrs)

~/Program_Files/miniconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py in __iter__(self)
    759 
    760     def __iter__(self):
--> 761         for key in self._mapping:
    762             yield self._mapping[key]
    763 

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

**Am I missing something in the way you remove a selfloop from a MultliDiGraph or is this a bug with NetworkX?**

Reproducible example demonstrating the unexpected error:

```
import networkx as nx

# create an empty MultiDiGraph
MG = nx.MultiDiGraph()

# add some edges to the graph
MG.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)])

# check the edges in the graph
MG.edges()

# remove selfloop edges from the graph
MG.remove_edges_from(MG.selfloop_edges())
```

This method works as expected with a DiGraph, as seen below:

```
# create an empty MultiDiGraph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add some edges to the graph
G.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)])

# check the edges in the graph
G.edges
OutEdgeView([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1)])

# remove selfloop edges from the graph
G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges())

# check the edges in the graph
G.edges()
OutEdgeView([(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1)])
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `MG.selfloop_edges()` is an iterator (more precisely generator) over the selfloop edges in the graph, and by removing the edges you are changing the iterator's edges during the iteration.

According to the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/reference/classes/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.remove_edges_from.html#networkx.MultiDiGraph.remove_edges_from):

> Parameters: ebunch (list or container of edge tuples) - ...

That means that the `ebunch` parameter should be a container, while `MG.selfloop_edges()` returns a generator. You can read more about the difference between the two [here](https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/).

The issue can be solved by passing **`list(MG.selfloop_edges())`** to `MG.remove_edges_from` (instead of passing `MG.selfloop_edges()` directly).

Comment: Since you'll always put a graph in there I suspect a bug unless OP is misusing the library. It must have worked in python 2 so perhaps it wasn't caught on the port to 3.

Comment: Documentation states the `ebunch` should be a list or container, and here a generator is passed. So at least according to the documentation it's ok that it fails. However, it's counterintuitive that the original code doesn't work, and can be easily fixed internally.

Comment: Thanks. I'd add that (preferably with doc link) to your answer, because that would change the meaning from "here's a workaround: ..." to "you're using it wrong" ;)

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak, added

Comment: The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.remove_edges_from.html#networkx.DiGraph.remove_edges_from) also states that the argument for `DiGraph.remove_edges_from()` is also an `ebunch`.  But for some reason, you can pass `G.selfloop_edges()` directly into that function and it doesn't complain.

Comment: I've added an answer below, explaining this.  But basically this is a bug that should go away once you update networkx.

Answer (score 1):

I address this issue in another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49428652/2966723

Right now you can do `MG.remove_edges_from(list(MG.selfloops_edges()))`.  However, this is actually a bug and will be fixed in an upcoming release: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/4080.  Then the code you wanted to write will work.