# How to remove loops from three nodes? [networkx]

Tags: loops, networkx

I have a graph with hundreds of edges and I want to remove loops like this:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

I have tried:

```
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))
```

But it does not seems to work. Any advices?

Comment: what version of networkx do you have?  (try `nx.__version__`)

Comment: I expect that you're using an older version of networkx in which case this answer probably helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427638/removing-self-loops-from-undirected-networkx-graph

Comment: @Joel I have 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selfloops are edges of a node to itself. For example, `(1,1)` or `(2,2)` are self loops. The example you is a simple cycle, i.e., a closed path were no node appears twice. You can use [`simple_cycle`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles) or [`find_cycle`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle). For example, you could iteratively use find cycle:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
print(nx.find_cycle(G, orientation="ignore"))
# [(0, 1, 'forward'), (1, 2, 'forward'), (2, 0, 'forward')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. this line: nx.find_cycle(G, orientation="ignore") return only first cycle. How to make it remove all?

Comment: You could simply add a loop around it. I'm not sure which edge (all, the first, a random), you want to remove to "break the loop". You can do this until the `NetworkXNoCycle` error is thrown. (It may take quite a while).